Embeding Lua with sol2 in C++ not working as intended with shared_ptr
I have a C++ Project and want to use Lua with sol2 for scripting but I have some trouble with shared_ptr.
There is a function in my class SceneNode which takes an shared_ptr as Argument, but I always get an error...
Function:
std::shared_ptr<SceneNode> SceneNode::addChild(std::shared_ptr<SceneNode> child)
{
    child->setParent(std::weak_ptr(shared_from_this()));
    children.push_back(child);

    return child;
}

Here I want to set everything up for Lua:
void setup_lua() {
    sol::state lua;
    lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);

    lua.new_usertype<SceneNode>("SceneNode",
        sol::constructors<
            void(),
            void(std::string)>(),
            //sol::base_classes, sol::bases<std::enable_shared_from_this<SceneNode>>(),
            "id", &SceneNode::id,
            "name", &SceneNode::name,
            "addChild", &SceneNode::addChild
        );

    lua.script_file("/Path/to/setup_lua.lua");
}

setup_lua.lua looks like this:
local node = SceneNode:new("node")
print(node.name)
print(node.id)

local childNode = SceneNode:new("child")
node:addChild(childNode)
print(childNode.name)
print(childNode.id)

print(node)
print(childNode)

When I run the program, I get this output:
node
-2472761803519894154
[sol2] An error occurred and has been passed to an error handler: sol: runtime error: stack index 2, expected userdata, received sol.SceneNode: value is a userdata but is not the correct unique usertype (bad argument into 'std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>(std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>)')
stack traceback:
        [C]: in method 'addChild'
        /Path/to/setup_lua.lua:13: in main chunk
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sol::error'
  what():  sol: runtime error: stack index 2, expected userdata, received sol.SceneNode: value is a userdata but is not the correct unique usertype (bad argument into 'std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>(std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>)')
stack traceback:
        [C]: in method 'addChild'
        /Path/to/setup_lua.lua:13: in main chunk
Aborted (core dumped)

I'm stuck on this since the last 3 days...
I tried to add a Child to my parent node but always get an error:
sol: runtime error: stack index 2, expected userdata, received sol.SceneNode: value is a userdata but is not the correct unique usertype (bad argument into 'std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>(std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>)')


"child->setParent(std::weak_ptr(shared_from_this()))" - why is there a weak_ptr conversion there? Also, the error message seems quite descriptive - how is it not helpful?

Its to avoid cyclical dependencies of shared ptr. But I dont get the problem Lua has with it. I'm completely new to Lua.
